# How to robustly determine which version of GCC was used to build the kernel from bash shell

Tags: bash, ubuntu, linux-kernel, gcc, version

What is a robust way in a bash shell to determine the version of GCC used to compile the currently running kernel? I need it in the form of `major.minor.patch` so that I can compare it with the last token of the first line in the output of `gcc --version`.

I have been parsing `/proc/version` using the following:

```
awk '{print $8}' /proc/version | tr -d ','
```

However, the version string I'm looking for does not always appear in the same location of the output of `/proc/version`. Is there a more robust approach? A solution that is robust for Ubuntu only will suffice, no need to make it distribution independent if that is more difficult.

Comment: Seeing this is specific to Ubuntu, do you use anything but the Ubuntu kernel packages to get your kernel?

Comment: there just might be free-form strings there, which would make naive parsing somewhat difficult... the man page says /proc/version contains the contents of /proc/sys/kernel/ostype, /proc/sys/kernel/osrelease and /proc/sys/kernel/version, but I don't see the compiler version in any of them. Maybe look for the string `gcc version`? (Unless Stephen wakes up to tell you where exactly to find that string :)

Comment: @ilkkachu The `linux-image` will download its own `gcc-version` as dependency independently of the default configured `gcc`.

Comment: @ConstantineA.B. I just use the default kernel from official Ubuntu repositories. Let’s assume that the user has not and will not manually take actions that change the kernel from default. Perhaps a rash assumption in general, but it is true for my use cases.

Comment: @AdamSperry then that kernel is built with the very same version of gcc you can install via apt-get.

Comment: @ConstantineA.B. This is normally true, but in Ubuntu 22.04 right now, the default compiler is gcc-11 and the latest default kernel is built with gcc-12. I need a way to detect this state automatically.

Comment: You could use `apt-get source` to get the source package to your kernel package, extract it, and grep through `debian/rules`. I'm sorry for the horrible advice...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have updated GAD3R's edit to show the correct output from his pastebin...

The patch for this went into the Linux kernel on 28/9/2022.

On Ubuntu check the `/boot/config-$(uname -r)`:

```
grep -i gcc /boot/config-$(uname -r)
 
CONFIG_CC_VERSION_TEXT="x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-12 (Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 12.3.0"
CONFIG_CC_IS_GCC=y
CONFIG_GCC_VERSION=120300
CONFIG_GCC11_NO_ARRAY_BOUNDS=y
CONFIG_HAVE_GCC_PLUGINS=y
```

This works with opensuse.

```
# gzip -dc /proc/config.gz | grep -i gcc

CONFIG_CC_VERSION_TEXT="gcc (SUSE Linux) 7.5.0"
CONFIG_CC_IS_GCC=y
CONFIG_GCC_VERSION=70500
CONFIG_HAVE_GCC_PLUGINS=y
```

Comment: Here is the output on Ubuntu Jammy  [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/fPiM1YmF). I am using  `gcc-13` as default gcc.

Comment: No CC version there on Ubuntu 20.04 (with 5.4 kernel)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas By the looks the commit was made back on 28/9/2022.

Comment: Just as an FYI, for MS WSL2, the 2nd version produces `CONFIG_CC_VERSION_TEXT="gcc (GCC) 11.2.0"` and `CONFIG_GCC_VERSION=110200` among other output.

Comment: There appears to be a typo in first line of this answer. I think that "On Ubuntu check the `/proc/config-$(uname -r)`" should be "On Ubuntu check the `/boot/config-$(uname -r)`" (the path uses `/boot/` in the example). I don't have a `/proc/config-$(uname -r)` on my system.

Comment: Thanks @AdamSperry.

Comment: @Bib: Was Ubuntu really built on SuSE?

Comment: @JohnDallman, no, that was an edit by GAD3R which was not fully updated. If you go to the link he provided, you'll see what should be returned.

Comment: The ‘Ubuntu’ method should work on pretty much any Debian derivative, not just Ubuntu (the config-in-boot thing is inherited from Debian). Additionally, the openSUSE method should work on most other common Linux distributions, though a majority will require a `modprobe configs` run as root beforehand.

Comment: Note: the CONFIG_CC_VERSION_TEXT variable, which contains the version in the format I’m looking for, is named differently and commented out in Ubuntu 18.04 so it appears that variable was the only recently standardized. I’ve accepted the answer regardless, because it appears CONFIG_GCC_VERSION has what I’m looking for. It’s just in a different format and I can manipulate it as needed.